# Scala - define a trait with generic methods

Tags: scala, generics

How do I define a trait with generic arguments in its methods and then override with the specific typed arguments?

An example:

```
import shapeless._

case class UserA(name:String)
case class UserB(name:String)

trait User {
  def save(item:Option[T]): Option[T]
}
class UserAdmin extends User {
  def save(item:Option[UserA]): Option[UserA]
}
class UserSomethingElse extends User {
  def save(item:Option[UserB]): Option[UserB]
}
```

With this, I get the error `not found: type T` even though it is defined in shapeless

Comment: I think that you might be confusing "Generic programming" (which is what shapeless is about) with "parametric polymorphism" which seems to be what you're concerned with in this question. I understand that this is confusing because "generics" is a term which is sometimes used to talk about parametric polymorphism.

Comment: Yes, you were definitely right.. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you something along these lines:

```
trait User[T] {
  def save(item:Option[T]): Option[T]
}
class UserAdmin extends User[UserA] {
  def save(item: Option[UserA]): Option[UserA] = ???
}
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option, besides @mfirry's is this, where we use a type member instead (versus a type parameter).

```
trait User {
  type T
  def save(item:Option[T]): Option[T]
}
class UserAdmin extends User {
  type T = UserA
  def save(item:Option[UserA]): Option[T]
}
class UserSomethingElse extends User {
  type T = UserB
  def save(item:Option[UserB]): Option[T]
}
```

In my real case this is actually better since I have several such types whose concrete implementations will vary in the subclasses (different types for the arguments and the return parameters). So something like this:

```
trait User {
  type T
  type R
  def save(item:Option[T]): Option[R]
}
class UserAdmin extends User {
  type T = UserA
  type R = UserAA
  def save(item:Option[T]): Option[R]
}
class UserSomethingElse extends User {
  type T = UserB
  type R = UserBB
  def save(item:Option[T]): Option[R]
}
```

This article was helpful: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=270195

Comment: Your answer saved me. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One has to keep in mind that `T` at this moment does not denote a `type` or `class` but is used as a placeholder. So it may be that there is a `T` in shapeless but it has no connection to the placeholder `T`.

Here is a nice introduction to `Type polymorphism`: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html.

So basically as @mfirry already suggested:

```
trait User[T] { // T is placeholder
  def save(item:Option[T]): Option[T]
}

new User[String] {
  // using override her is considered best practice
  override def save(item:Option[String]): Option[String] = item
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was definitely confusing shapeless with the T placeholder. This articles also helped http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=270195